# saving bash functions

Tags: bash, shell

First of all,  I'd like to be corrected on my vocabulary. I assume Terminal provides an environment for bash, which is a type/version of shell.  Is this correct?

I'm trying to utilize bash and shell more in my development processes to speed up deployment.  However, I'm only beginning to understand the basics outside the commands I've learned from growing up.

I've started making functions in Terminal to help automate some of my more repetitious tasks.  This is all find and dandy until I exit terminal.

I assume that shell runs in an instance, so that instance is lost when I exit terminal.  I notice that shell leaves a .bash_history, also accessible using 'history', where I can see my old functions from old sessions.  However, of course, they no longer appear to execute.

I recognize that I could create a shell script, but this introduces compiling issues as well as having to pay more attention to where the scripts are stored relatively.

Question:  When I create bash scripts using command(){},  they do not persist after closing the terminal.  Can I make them do that so on new terminal sessions I have access to my old functions without resorting to shell scripts?

---

Edit: I also wanted to mention that I tried extensively to find an issue to this using traditional means, but "save" and "exit" in the search term often will direct to other aspects of shell.

Comment: Not quite. The "terminal" is the program that turns the text that the shell outputs into pixels on the screen, and turns keyboard presses into text that goes into the shell. This question is all about the shell, and not the terminal. I'll retag it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement is correct.  A terminal instance runs a type of shell (bash, sh, csh)

You can add them to your ~/.bashrc file or add the saved script path (no compiling needed) to your PATH variable.

You could also just copy scripts to /usr/local/bin for quick access anytime.  You would have no need to keep track of where they are relatively.  This is quite handy and makes your scripts available to other users (or not if permissions are set correctly)

Answer (score 2):

See the [Using History Interactively](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC123) section of the Bash Reference Manual for ways you can execute commands from your history.

For example, typing `!?foo` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute the most recent command containing "foo". I like to have `shopt -s histverify histreedit` in my `~/.bashrc` so I can edit and confirm the command, if necessary rather than executing it immediately.

Also see the [Commands For Manipulating The History](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC110) section for keystrokes you can use to search for history entries to recall and execute.

For example, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and typing `foo` will recall the most recent command containing "foo". You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> additional times to continue searching in reverse for additional matching commands. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're ready to execute the one currently shown or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to abort the search.

If you add `stty -ixon` to your `~/.bashrc`, then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to search forward through history after you've begun searching backward.

Of course, you can save your functions by editing `~/.bashrc` and adding them to it. I prefer to keep my functions in a file I created called `~/bin/functions` and then add a line to `~/.bashrc` to source that file. The line looks like `. ~/bin/functions`.

I save larger scripts in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`. The former should already be in your path and you can add the latter to your path by editing `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

After you type in the functions on the command-line you could recall them using command-line editing (as @Dennis Williamson mentioned), but there is an easier method: `declare -f`.  This command lists all current functions, and you can redirect them to a file:

```
home/user1> function myfunc {
> echo "Hollow world!"
> }

/home/user1> declare -f > myfuncs
/home/user1> more myfuncs
myfunc () 
{ 
    echo "Hollow world"
}
```

Note how Bash changes the function syntax from Korn shell to Bourne shell!  Fortunately there is no difference between the two in Bash (unlike ksh93).

When you need to load the function it is a simple matter:

```
/home/user1> source myfuncs
/home/user1> myfunc
Hollow world!
```

You don't need execute permissions by the way, only read.
You could (as others have said) add this to one of your start-up files, like `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple library which would contain all your functions. This would basically solve your problem of storing functions.

```
 yeshwantnaik$ cat my_functions.lib
function do_something(){
 #your code goes here
}
```

Save it wherever you want. Preferably to your $HOME directory.

Load the library. Don't miss the dot in the beginning.

```
 yeshwantnaik$ . $HOME/my_functions.lib
```

Now you can run your function directly.

```
 yeshwantnaik$ do_something
```

### Let Linux do stuff for you

You can skip the step of manually loading the library by letting Linux do it for you when you log in automatically.

Run below commands

```
echo ". $HOME/my_functions.lib" >> ~/.bashrc
echo ". $HOME/my_functions.lib" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_profile
```

That's it. You can directly execute your function from the command line without doing anything.